# Enabling UFW breaks all http and https connections

Tags: linux, iptables, https, http, ufw

I have an Oracle VPS with Ubuntu. Before enabling ufw everything worked perfect. I've added rules for ssh, http, https and openvpn. After enabling it ssh stopped working, but after rebooting my VPS it worked fine. But http and https stopeed working! My webserver still is running, and listening at 0.0.0.0:80/0.0.0.0:443. Curl'ing my VPS didn't result in `Connection refused` but `Couldn't connect to server`, both on http and https. The oracle firewall is set to allow everything, but it hasn't changed since I first activated the VPS. Syslog does not show anything about it. Even disabling the UFW and rebooting does not work. Curl'ing the VPS public IP from the VPS itself returns `No route to host`, but curling the localhost does work. Pinging works normally, both from the VPS and my PC.

UFW rules:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
1194                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

iptables rules:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N InstanceServices
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-966797238e10 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-966797238e10 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-966797238e10 ! -o br-966797238e10 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-966797238e10 -o br-966797238e10 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o pterodactyl0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o pterodactyl0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i pterodactyl0 ! -o pterodactyl0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i pterodactyl0 -o pterodactyl0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-ffd2ff4d968f -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-ffd2ff4d968f -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-ffd2ff4d968f ! -o br-ffd2ff4d968f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-ffd2ff4d968f -o br-ffd2ff4d968f -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d12331003458 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d12331003458 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-d12331003458 ! -o br-d12331003458 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-d12331003458 -o br-d12331003458 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j InstanceServices
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-966797238e10 ! -o br-966797238e10 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i pterodactyl0 ! -o pterodactyl0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-ffd2ff4d968f ! -o br-ffd2ff4d968f -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-d12331003458 ! -o br-d12331003458 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-966797238e10 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o pterodactyl0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-ffd2ff4d968f -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-d12331003458 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.2.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.4.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.5.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.3/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.0/16 -p udp -m udp -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```